# Printing to a file?

Tags: python

I have the following code. I am trying to make the code save the print to the file at the end of the file. What part of this would I be missing?

```
import itertools

#Open test.txt
file = open('test.txt', 'a')

res = itertools.product('abcdef', repeat=3) # 3 is the length of your result.
for i in res: 
    print ''.join(i)
```

Comment: There's no link between opening the file for writing and actual writing to the file.

Comment: In Python 2, where `print` is a statement, you need to use `print ''.join(i) >> file` to direct the output to an open file. In Python 3 where it's function, use `print(''.join(i), file=file)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically didn't link your printing with writing to the file, as `print` prints the output to the `stdout` which by default is your screen, although it can be changed of course.

In my example, I used the `with` statement, which means the file will be automatically closed once the code below it finishes to execute, hence you don't need to remember close the file when done processing.

For more information about `with` you can read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)

You can do something like:

```
import itertools

res = itertools.product('abcdef', repeat=3) # 3 is the length of your result.
with open('test.txt', 'a') as f_output:
    for i in res: 
        f_output.write(''.join(i))
        f_output.write('\n')
```

Comment: `with open() as filevar:` is a best practice.